# $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} f)^2+(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} f)^2 + (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3} f)^2 = (\frac{\partial}{\partial r} f)^2$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a radial function(i.e.$f(x)=f(r), r=|x|$).

It holds that

$(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} f)^2+(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} f)^2 + (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3} f)^2 = (\frac{\partial}{\partial r} f)^2$

because

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}f= \sin\theta\cos\phi \frac{\partial}{\partial r}f,  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}f= \sin\theta\sin\phi \frac{\partial}{\partial r}f, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}f= \cos\phi \frac{\partial}{\partial r}f$.

I want to prove

$(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} f)^2+(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} f)^2 + (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3} f)^2 = (\frac{\partial}{\partial r} f)^2$

by definition;

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} f(x)= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+he_i)-f(x)}{h}\ \ $ ($e_1=(1,0,0), e_2=(0,1,0), e_3=(0,0,1)$) and

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial r} f(r)= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(r+h)-f(r)}{h}$.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this a straightforward application of the chain rule? for clarity, give another name to what you called $f(r)$. So $f(x)=g(r(x))$ with $r(x)=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}$. Then $\partial_k f(x)=\partial_kr(x)g'(r(x))$. It's straightforward to obtain $\partial_kr(x)=x_k/r(x)$, and you're done. By the way, this works in any dimension, not just dimension $3$.

Comment: How do you define $|x|$ for $x\in\Bbb R^3$? The usual norm on $\Bbb R^3$ has range $\Bbb R^+\cup\{0\}$ which is different from $\Bbb R^3$ (thus making $f(x)=f(|x|)$ meaningless).